# Get sum of database column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sum

I have a database table 'posts' with 3 columns: Title, content and amount. amount has a decimal data type and I'm trying to get the sum for amount for all posts.

I'd like to display this sum on the index route subtracted from the instance variable `@balance`.

This is the action in my controller

```
def index
    @posts = Post.all
    @balance = 300
    @spendingtotal = @balance - @posts.amount
end
```

However this is giving me an error: undefined method `amount' for #

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`Enumerable#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject):

```
@spendingtotal = @balance - @posts.amount.inject(0) { |sum, post|
  sum + post.amount
}
```

Using [`ActiveRecord::Calculations#sum`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum) method is more preferable:

```
@spendingtotal = @balance - Post.sum('amount')
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much falsetru. So simple and elegant and works brilliantly.

Answer (score 3):

`@posts` is an array.That why the error occurs.You can use

```
@spendingtotal = @balance - Post.sum(:amount)
```

as mentioned by @falsetru